# Layer design in an application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have been writing applications which are layered as:

DB<->DAL<->BL<->Service<->Presentation

And that's all that get's referenced. That is, The Presentation doesn't have a reference to the DAL.

We have a new app to write for a client, and the client is proposing something that is foreign to me. That is, the WRITE flow goes through the SL, but to READ data from the database, the want us to have a linq query in the presentation, direct to the DAL. That seems strange, but I am being told that my way is old fashioned and that my way, and their proposed way is essentially the same thing.

Also, my business logic usually resides in the BL, which is a separate project. But the client wants the business logic to be in the DTO object's themselves.

Is this normal? Is this basically Domain Driven Development or something? I find it strange that the linq calls to get the data for a form, is in the presentation layer, as opposed to my idea of a service layer method:

```
public MyPersonObject GetPersonByPersonId(int personId)
```

And then the same method in the Business, which might apply some rules to what is got, and then the same method in the DAL, which has the Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client is client, did you ever hear [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)?

Your client might be affected by CQRS which is a new architecture fashion in domain driven design. In general, it separates command and query in different ways to database.

But in your client's proposed approach, it seems mixed up between traditional DDD and CQRS which does not use [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) inside. But it is still okay and normal, IMHO, query which provides data for presentation layer is trivial and it is not essentially complicated. It is like the report system which just queries data from database, you don't need to use ORM for this.

> Also, my business logic usually resides in the BL, which is a separate project. But the client wants the business logic to be in the DTO object's themselves.

Business logic should be in domain entity, if not, seem you are violating [Anemic Model anti pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), it is also not in DTO. DTO is the concept of data transfer object between distribution layer with consumer.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is in no way DDD. While some DDD implementations do use a split architecture for queries and commands (CQRS approach), it doesn't remove the need for good layering of your application.

If writes go through a Service layer, it probably means that your software is at least of reasonable complexity and as such, should decouple presentation from persistence with a layer of abstraction in between. In CQRS, that layer often takes the form of Facades that accept queries and return DTO's containing the required data.

> But the client wants the business logic to be in the DTO object's
>   themselves.

DTO stands for Data Transfer Object. DTO's don't contain any business logic and have no other purpose but to carry data.